# Terraform - Dynamically create resources in AWS security group

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I would like to re-use existing terraform security group module across different services.

Following is the folder structure:

```
├───qa
│   └───services
│       ├───service-1
│       │       main.tf
│       │       outputs.tf
│       │       terraform.tfvars
│       │       variables.tf
│       └───service-2
│               main.tf
│               outputs.tf               
│               terraform.tfvars
│               variables.tf
└───modules
    │───rds
    │───redis
    ├───sg       
    └───vpc
```

**modules/sg.tf):**

```
resource "aws_security_group" "rds" {
  name_prefix = "rds_${service_1}_${var.env}"
  vpc_id      = var.vpc_id
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "rds_ingress_rules" {
  count = length(var.rds_ingress_rules)

  type              = "ingress"
  from_port         = var.rds_ingress_rules[count.index].from_port
  to_port           = var.rds_ingress_rules[count.index].to_port
  protocol          = var.rds_ingress_rules[count.index].protocol
  cidr_blocks       = [var.rds_ingress_rules[count.index].cidr_block]  
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.rds.id
}
```

**service1/main.tf**

```
module "sg" {
  source                                 = "../modules/sg"
  ---
  rds_ingress_rules                   = var.rds_ingress_rules
  ---
}
```

**service2/main.tf**

```
module "sg" {
  source                                 = "../modules/sg"
  ---
  
}
```

The security group resources for rds is required to be created only for service-1 but not for service-2.

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Please let me know if you need further info

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is configure the security group resource to depend on the length of the `rds_ingress_rules` variable:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "rds" {
  count       = length(var.rds_ingress_rules) > 0 ? 1 : 0
  name_prefix = "rds_service_1_${var.env}"
  vpc_id      = var.vpc_id
}
```

Also, it's a bad practice to hard-code names in modules, so for the name prefix you could do something like:

```
name_prefix = "rds_service_${count.index + 1}_${var.env}"
```

But that is also not the "cleanest" approach.

Comment: Thank you Marko. I will try and let you know